# what type of html is this?

Tags: php, html

im fall in this peace of code and i was wondering how it was written??
is it an encryption? or it was written like that

```
$code="

<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang=\"en\"> 
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=UTF-8\">
<!-- ".gen_rand(rand(500,750))." --><head>   
<!-- ".gen_rand(rand(500,750))." --><meta charset=\"utf-8\"> <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no\">
```

Comment: this may html code within php.

Comment: Yes It is within PHP ,but How This HTML Code was Written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a terrible form of writing HTML. It has the HTML5 doctype.

Seems like PHP, and the quotes withing the `$code` are escaped with `\`.

Whatever you do, don't do it like this. Take your html template and add PHP to it, not the other way around.

If you need to print a html tag withing PHP, you could do it like this, without having to escape anything.

```
$myUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com";
echo '<a href="'.$myUrl.'">Link title</a>';
```

Here's how to convert it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
  <head>   
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- <?php echo gen_rand(rand(500,750)); ?>-->
    <!-- <?php echo gen_rand(rand(500,750)); ?> -->
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Take note that `meta` tags reside in `head`, not in `body` or anywhere else.

It's nothing special. Just escaped string as PHP variables (specifically strings) are declared with quotes or single quotes. Unnecessary escaping as

```
$code = "String";
$code = 'String';
```

Do the exact same thing.

Probably the real use for quotes inside string would be inline javascript paired with html, as it looks like this:

```
<a onclick="alert('Cat');">Alert cat</a>
```

And you would escape it like this to be able to print it using PHP

```
echo "<a onclick=\"alert('Cat');\">Alert cat</a>";
```

Comment: u didnt Got it Sir;
it is not my own code im asking how this code was written 
it is html within php yes But how that html is written and why !!

Comment: I did get it, it's not your code. It's written by writing it. Specifically in variable `$code` and then probably printed using `echo`.

Comment: Yes Thats It ;
but the problem Here is why it was written that why and would u please explain How it is converted
or how to do smth like it i mean replacing slach by backslash wich is new for me please explain more so we can understand from ur exeprience

Comment: It's written like that because someone who had no idea of what he was doing wrote it like that. If you want to convert it, see my edit. @LambertLauryne

Comment: @ArtjomB. Sorry, my bad. Long day.